# Spark: bad idea to use inferSchema = False (infer all as strings) then cast columns as needed?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

We have a need to get a huge amount of data into Delta tables from .csv.gz files fast. Several hundred Terabytes. Most of these tables will be used for analysis purposes by people who know the data pretty well.

Is it a bad idea to do `spark.read.option("inferSchema", "false").csv(path) # << default option` to get the data into tables and let the end users cast columns as needed? The reason I ask is we have no column schemas available to us *at the moment*, but we have a need to get this data into tables ASAP. I am assuming there won't be any bad casting or anything if we simply use string for everything, then later when we get some DDL statements from the original database we could write scripts to cast columns as needed *or* the end-users/analysts could cast columns if needed one-by-one. Additionally, these files are split up so to run `inferSchema=True` would mean needing to iterate over several dozen files (Terabytes) and inferring from that scan which is super, super intense and slow.

Is this a bad idea? or given the business need is it fine and using strings for all columns for now won't harm anything (other than probably slightly larger data size than needed).

Comment: You can take a look at [samplingRatio](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html?highlight=samplingratio#pyspark-sql-dataframereader-csv)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than infer specifying a schema would likely be preferrable, you state exactly what the types should be up front. Inferring doesn't require scans of every file (although mergeschema may) but, as such, it's prone to mistakes.

[DataFrameReader.schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#schema(schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader), per the docs, can also be faster for reading json or csv than inference.

Again although opinion heavy, specifying your own schema directly gives you more flexibility and you can always elect that certain fields remain strings and are converted in a separate select/projection.

Pay attention to the available [csv options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option), you may want enforceSchema to be false for example.